# Handle the change of TMenuItem.Action.Visible in Delphi

Tags: delphi

in Delphi I want to handle the change of the `TMenuItem.Action.Visible` property for a menu item. This is placed as popup menu item in the `TAdvGlowButton.DropDownMenu` property.

First I tried using the `OnUpdate` event of the `TAction`, but this is raised too late when the menu pops up and not when the change of the `Visible` property is really done.

Also overwriting of the `ActionLink.OnChange` property of the menu item with a handler, which executes both the origin handler and an own one, does not help.

Has anyone an idea to solve this problem?

I want the event handler to be raised when the `Visible` property is set and not only when the menu is popped up.

The actions are not created by me. So I cannot change the type of them to make this event accessable from outside (protected -> public).

Comment: Normally, you use the action's `OnUpdate` event handler for this. That has always worked for me. You might want to be more clear about what you need.

Comment: I want the event handler to be raised when the Visible-property is set and not only when the menu is popped up.

Comment: What about the OnChange event of the Action - not the ActionLink?

Comment: The actions are not created by me. So I cannot change the type of them to make this event accessable from outside (protected -> public)

Comment: You can use a class helper to access the protected OnChange event in code. That won't allow to wire that event in the Object Inspector, though.

Comment: How do you mean it exactly?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/UweRaabe/8de8faa1d11c9689e5444c36e0c2ab25

Comment: Your suggestion works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious place to act on changing the `Visible` property of an action would be its `OnChange` event. Unfortunately this event is not `public`, let alone `published`.

Nevertheless there is is a way to set an event handler to the `OnChange` event by using a `class helper`.

Create the `class helper` in a new (or suitable existing) unit. This is a working example:

```
unit ActionHelper;

interface

type
  TActionHelper = class helper for TBasicAction
  private
    function GetOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure SetOnChange(const Value: TNotifyEvent);
  public
    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read GetOnChange write SetOnChange;
  end;

implementation

function TActionHelper.GetOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  Result := inherited OnChange;
end;

procedure TActionHelper.SetOnChange(const Value: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  inherited OnChange := Value;
end;

end.
```

Whenever you add this unit to a uses clause, you will be able to connect the `OnChange` property of any `TBasicAction` descendant to an appropriate event handler.

Although this till doesn't allow to wire the `OnChange` event within the *Object Inspector*, it is a pretty convenient way to get notified whenever some action property changes.